# Web browser is having problem on processing js in UTF-8

Tags: firefox, javascript, chinese

I am using Firefox 20.0, but once I was browsing a website(Chinese) and the Lunar Calendar javascript got something like NaN or Undefined. The website has been tested under iPod, Firefox in Windows (Also the latest version) and even Gentoo Linux with Konqueror and Firefox.

The javascript is here: http://www.hanchc.com/static/js/nongli.js

The minimum test page is http://fitgirl.org/testpage.htm (Chinese)

Application that might related to this post are with these versions:

```
~ # firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 20.0

>~ # uname -a
Linux Steph-Zhang 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript is OK, the problem is the character encoding. Select the character encoding Unicode (UTF-16LE) in either Chromium browser or Epiphany. Firefox doesn't have the UTF-16LE character encoding.

Comment: Yes epiphany works well. But the problem became why the Firefox in Ubuntu doesn't have UTF-16LE. My Gentoo Linux with firefox can run the script correctly.